# Error while compiling gRPC protobuffs using python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I can't seem to autogenerate my Proto file to python code. I've managed to do it earlier but now I'm really at a loss. I am currently in the directory where the `.proto` file resides and I have entered the following into my terminal:

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=. --python_out=. --grpc_python_out =. filetransfertest.proto
```

And what I get is `=./: No such file or directory`

Any help is greatly appreciated since it will help a great deal with my current mental state.

Comment: Tried moving out to working directory where the virtualenv was, just in case: 
`python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=. ./A3/src/protofiles --python_out=. ./A3/src/protofiles --grpc_python_out =. ./A3/src/protofiles/filetransfertest.proto`
This should produce the same but it only says:
`Could not map to virtual file: ./A3/src/protofiles: Input file is a directory.`

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

In the end ist seems like the space between `--grpc_python_out` and `=` was the main contributing factor. I also changed the paths to absolute paths

`python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=/Users/..../A3/src/protofiles --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. filetransfertest.proto`

Devil in the details and so on...